# Converter power loss and efficiency: Is there an error here, or am I just misunderstanding these two facts?

Tags: power-electronics, converter

I am currently reading the textbook *Fundamentals of Power Electronics*, third edition, by Robert W. Maksimovic and Dragan Erickson. In the introduction, the authors say the following:

> High efficiency is essential in any power processing application. The primary reason for this is usually not the desire to save money on one’s electric bills, nor to conserve energy, in spite of the nobility of such pursuits. Rather, high efficiency converters are necessary because construction of low-efficiency converters, producing substantial output power, is impractical. The efficiency of a converter having output power \$P_{out}\$ and input power \$P_{in}\$ is
> $$\eta = \dfrac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} \tag{1.1}$$
> The power lost in the converter \$P_{loss} = P_{in} - P_{out}\$ can be related to the output power as
> $$Q = \dfrac{P_{out}}{P_{loss}} = \dfrac{\eta}{1 - \eta} \tag{1.2}$$
> Equation (1.2) is plotted in Fig. 1.3. The quantity \$Q = P_{out}/P_{loss}\$ is a fundamental measure of the quality of the power converter. The loss \$P_{loss}\$ is converted into heat by the converter circuit elements and must be removed by a cooling system.
> [image]

There are a couple of things here that confuse me. First of all, the authors say that equation (1.2) is plotted in Fig. 1.3, but Fig. 1.3 shows \$\eta\$ and \$\dfrac{P_{loss}}{P_{out}}\$, rather than \$\dfrac{\eta}{1 - \eta}\$ and \$P_{out}/P_{loss}\$. Furthermore, it isn't clear to me how one gets \$Q = \dfrac{P_{out}}{P_{loss}} = \dfrac{\eta}{1 - \eta}\$ from \$\eta = \dfrac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\$ and \$P_{loss} = P_{in} - P_{out}\$. Is there an error here, or am I just misunderstanding these two facts?

Comment: Since Pout/Ploss = eta/(1-eta) I'm not at all sure why anyone would bother to plot one against the other. It would just be a line at 45 degrees. Note that eta <> Ploss/Pout. So this plot *may* be something other than a straight line. Also, you can easily check their curve. It should be the case that Ploss/Pout = 1/eta-1. For example, 1/.4 - 1 = 1.5. And that matches a point on the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships shown by the authors can be found by simple manipulations as illustrated below:

[image]

As you rightfully pointed out, you need to plot 1/Q to obtain the curve they display and I agree that it can be misleading at first sight but all is correct. The important point here is that efficient converters require less heatsinking and means to evacuate the power lost in heat leading towards compact and light power supplies in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Once the author has said $$\eta = \dfrac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} \tag{1.1}$$
he's said all that needs to be said.

He goes on to demonstrate that you can play around with the algebra to define other quantities like Q, which presumably means 'quality factor', which is output/loss, which is no more 'fundamental' than \$\eta\$ which is output/input. I've not heard the term Q used in this context before.

The fact that you can use one term or the other equally well to describe a lossy system is clearly demonstrated by the fact that he said he was going to plot Q, and then plotted \$\eta\$ againt 1/Q, and that error got past him, his proof readers, and the publisher.

You're quite right to be confused by this error, and then the equations which seem to be trying to justify the different ways of looking at it, when I think they're only justifying padding out that chapter with correct but irrelevant algebra. There's no error here, but it's not 'two facts'. It's a single fact, with the algebra rearranged for whatever reason.

Once you have defined the terms P<sub>in</sub> and P<sub>out</sub>, P<sub>loss</sub> is trivially the difference, and then you can choose which ratios you find most interesting. \$\eta\$ for efficiency is the one most people use. As far as I can see, the author is consistent in relating all the terms he has defined.

If you want to find the loss in a device that's consuming a certain input power or producing a certain output power, most people would just do the trivial sums from \$\eta\$, rather than define new quantities like Q.

Answer (score 0):

The author could have said that a power converter that is less efficient than in could be dissipates more energy as heat than it would otherwise need to dissipate. Dissipating more heat requires more air circulation and more heat-transfer surface area. That increases the physical size of the product and the cost of materials and components used for heat removal. That is not impractical it is costly and inconvenient for the user. What is impractical is the author's approach to the problem.